# Calacuted field in SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a query which give 4 columns

EXPR1, EXPR2, MOVE5 and qty

qty is the same value for all (6360)

I want to be able to adapt the query so that a new calculated field is generated for each row which is the qty + EXPR2 but the qty used from each row will be the result from the previous calculation but starting from the initial qty.

```
e.g. 
row 1 (1,400,6360,6360)
row2 (-10,401,6360,6350)
row3 (-1,402,6360,6349)  etc


SELECT
    movement_reference AS EXPR1,
    movement_quantity AS EXPR2,
    CAST (CAST(movement_date AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)) + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(CAST(sequence_no AS INT) AS VARCHAR(6)), 6) AS MOVE5,
    (SELECT physical_qty FROM  stocktable WHERE (product = 'B') AND (warehouse = 'FH')) AS qty
FROM
    stockhistory
WHERE
    (warehouse = 'FH') 
AND
    (product = 'B')
ORDER BY
    dated DESC
```

Using SQL Server 2000.

Comment: @Tanner : Common table expressions were introduced in SQL Server 2005.
Emma: Subquery might Help-out

Comment: @Ragul of course, missed the 2000 part

Comment: It is not clear enough what you want to achive, plase give us a clear output and examples.

Comment: You can use a triangular join to solve it, something like: select *, qty + (select sum(EXPR2) from yourtable y2 where y2.id = y.id and y2.date < y.date) from yourtable y